# How to disable code inspection errors in README.md file in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, markdown, readme, intellij-inspections

In my GitHub `README.md` file, which is in the root of my Android project, I have code snippets like the following ones:

````
```xml
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

```java
MongolToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ᠰᠠᠢᠨ ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ ᠤᠤ︖", MongolToast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```
````

However, in Android Studio these code snippets give errors

[image]

I don't want to be warned of supposed code errors in the README file. How do I disable all errors here?

**Notes:**

- I know how to suppress inspections normally in code with `@SuppressLint` or going into settings and unchecking the lint inspection. I don't want these errors to be suppressed in other areas of my project, though.
- Somewhat similar question (without an answer): [Android Studio - disable errors highlighting for excluded files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32483265/android-studio-disable-errors-highlighting-for-excluded-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After doing some further research I come to conclusion that these errors are not from Android Studio itself but there are plugins for `markdown` format like [`Markdown Navigator`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7896-markdown-navigator) and [`Markdown Support`](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7793-markdown-support) if any of them is installed and enabled then you will see above errors in `README.md` file.

I think this spell check is built in feature of these plugins and can not be controlled from Android Studio.

One option what I think is to disable these plugins and you are good to go.

You can disable these plugins from (Android Studio 3.1.4 MacOS) `Preferences > Plugins` (or `File > Settings > Plugins` in Linux) by unchecking them and restart (don't forget it) your Android Studio:

[image]

Comment: For whatever help the plugin gave, I much prefer disabling it and not having the errors.

Comment: @Suragch this is the only option to get rid of those errors in markdown file. As I suspected rusito23's solution works only for non-markdown files only.

Comment: The new version of Android studio preinstalled plugin "Markdown" as default that shows errors, too. The only option is to uncheck the plugin.

Comment: What a piece of garbage... Unbelievable...

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a scope (Settings->Scope)
and add the files you want to keep out of scope for the Lints you wanna suppress.

Then go to Settings->Inspections, chose the inspection you wanna remove,
and then on the right choose from the drop down your scope to define the wanted behavior.

[image: scope_behavior]

In this case, my scope is called AVOID_LINTS, and won't show any typo warnings.

#### EDIT

In the first step, when you create the scope, you need to add your README to the new scope.

#### EDIT2

Where to find the scopes:
[image]

You may search for the files you want to add, select and click `include`.

Comment: OP needs only for README file. Your answer will avoid lints for whole project.

Comment: Maybe first paragraph wasn't clear. In your new scope you need to ADD the README.md. Then continue with the steps. Fixing the answer now. Tx!

Comment: did you test it? I am not able to find `Scope` in Android studio settings? Which version you are using?

Comment: Yes and I use this config too. I use Android Studio 3.1.3 on macOS. Maybe using the search bar you will find it. (Settings->Appearance and Behavior->Scopes)

Comment: I tried exactly what you have mentioned but somehow it is not working for me in case of `README.md` file, either I am not doing it correctly or this solution works for non-markdown files (I maybe wrong). As per my understanding those errors are coming from Markdown plugin. Please check my answer.

Comment: Think you are right, I don’t use md plugin really. Works for other files tho.

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of Android Studio starting with 2022.2.1 Flamingo (at least from Beta 1) have an option to toggle "Show problems in code fences" under `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Markdown`.

Note that this toggles all problem types at the same time (typos, warnings and errors).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove code type annotation, change from:

````
```xml
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

```java
MongolToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ᠰᠠᠢᠨ ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ ᠤᠤ︖", MongolToast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```
````

change to:

````
```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

```
MongolToast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ᠰᠠᠢᠨ ᠪᠠᠢᠨ᠎ᠠ ᠤᠤ︖", MongolToast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Before:

[image]

In android studio go to:

**Settings** -> **Languages & Frameworks** -> **Markdown**

untick **Inject languages in code fences**

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: The question is about how to disable inspection errors, not disable all language features. And a very [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75441209/1255289) doing that has already been provided.

Comment: I have edited the answer again. Please try it now. I hve given the answer according to the question. Language inspection will not work only in marksheet.

Comment: But this does not just disable inspection. It disables *all* language features, including highlighting and code completion. The answer I linked to above does what the question asks: it only disables code inspection errors. You can see the checkbox right in your own screenshot.

Comment: Ok @miken32 you are right at this point and i think there is solution for this point till now.